# Changing label forecolour using Angular js in Asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs

I have started learning Angularjs and i am trying to implement in my project but Confused with condition.

What i want:-

I have few button with different colors and upon click of those buttons i want to change color of selected label. For selected label i have taken hidden field which stores value of label clicked.
So I want to first check that hidden field value and then change its color based on button click.
I came across these

```
<input type="button" value="Red" ng-click="myStyle={color:'red'}"> 
<label id="lbl1" ng-style="myStyle">
<label id=lbl2"  ng-style="myStyle" >
<input id="hf" type="hidden" runat="server" />
```

But this will change color for all labels But i want to change for only one control based on hf value.
Hope its Understanable.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="myController">
    <input  type="button" value="Red" ng-click="updateColor()"> 
    <label id="lbl1" ng-style="myStyle">test</label>
    <label id="lbl2"  ng-style="myStyle">test2</label>
<input id="hf" 
        name="hf" 
        type="text" 
        runat="server" 
        value="lbl1" 
        ng-model="hf"/>

    <pre>myStyle={{myStyle}}</pre>
        <pre>hf={{hf}}</pre>
    </div>


function myController($scope){

    $scope.hf = document.getElementById('hf').value;

    $scope.updateColor = function(){

       document.getElementById($scope.hf).style.color = 'red';

    }

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pa2yLtqz/

Comment: Your answer is good but mystyle is not used....So its mostly javascript and angular js is of not use...Also $scope.hf can simply be replaced with hf's value so ng-model is also a waste.

Comment: Alok,there are 100 ways to drink water. ;)

Comment: 100 is to much....and m not saying that you are wrong but i wanna implement it using Angular js so that i can even learn that.

Comment: What you are trying to do still requires logic in the controller. So you would just have to determine how best to accomplish that.

Comment: Using javascript will not require i can simply call this function by passing color as parameter.

Comment: you have this...
 <label id="lbl1" ng-style="myStyle">test</label>
    <label id="lbl2"  ng-style="myStyle">test2</label>
So both are going to get updated no matter what you do as long as you are trying to use the myStyle var. Good luck!

Comment: When using javascript ng-style is of no use. I can get value of hf as you have showed above and in hf i am storing label id so based on id i got i can change its style using document.getElementById.

Comment: Your are correct. I think for what you are trying to do, I would not use ng-style :)

Comment: Yes...its just that i wanted to learn anulgarjs and thats y i was trying to implement it using that. Anyways thanks for helping.